# I can't find the unexpected error in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi i can't find where the error is

```
g1<-ggplot()+geom_bar(data=ventas2,aes(x=time,y=values,fill=mot_nrg),stat="identity",width=.6)+scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("DIE","PET"),values=c("#EB9486","#9ED8DB","blue"))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=brks,labels=lbls)+coord_flip()+labs(title="Engine Consumption")+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=.5)),axisTicks(element_blank())+geom_text(data=ventas2,aes(label=abs(values),x=time,y=values),fontface="bold")+geom_line(data=ventas2,aes(x=time,y=values,group=1,size=0.7,linetype="dashed")+geom_point(data=ventas2,aes(x=time,y=values),color="#2374AB",show.legend = FALSE)+theme(text=element_text(size=16,family="American Typewriter",face="bold"),plot.title = element_text(size=20,family="serif",hjust=0.5),legend.position = "bottom")

**Error: inesperado ',' in "lues,fill=mot_nrg),stat="identity",width=.6)+scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("DIE","PET"),values=c("#EB9486","#9ED8DB","blue"))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=brks,labels=lbls)+coord_flip()+labs(title=""**
```

please heelp

Comment: I added cod formatting to your question - could you please add line breaks and spaces to make it easier to read? It looks like you may have an extra `)` in your `theme()`, but it's hard to tell when everything is on one big line.

Comment: You have error in theme which you should replace by `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=.5),axisTicks = element_blank())`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a parenthesis here:

```
geom_line(data=ventas2,aes(x=time,y=values,group=1,size=0.7,linetype="dashed")+
```

geom_line should have 2 ending parenthisis and I can see only one.

TIP: Press enter in every ending + sign in you RStudio and it will indent your code automathically ;)